# Can you remove the Python folder from Applications after install?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, installation

Hopefully a simple question,

When installing Python 3.7 on a Mac, can you remove the folder from Applications containing the IDLE and the Launcher without breaking the install? I don't have an IDLE for the 2.7 that is built-into the Mac and don't want one for 3.7 either.

PS: I already removed it, but I would like to know if indeed something breaks as a result of this; if not, then I shall leave it as is.

Comment: What Python package are you using? Anaconda?

Comment: @ivallesp I've just installed it straight from the Mac .pkg installer at https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/.

Comment: I'd suggest you installing anaconda instead. Look at this link: https://www.anaconda.com

Comment: @ivallesp Isn't this for machine learning and data science?

Comment: I only plan on using Python for casual programming.

Comment: Not only, it is a general purpose Python manager. It makes several things much easier

Comment: @ivallesp I will take a look, thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the Python folder in /Applications will cause no problems. The contents are the IDLE.app for writing python, the Python Launcher app, which provides a configurable way to run python scripts by double-clicking them in the Finder, some documentation, and a couple of shell scripts to configure the installation.

'Actual python' that you call in the Terminal with all its libraries and dependencies is stored in /Library.

The entire folder is less than 1 Mb, (excluding the Extras folder that comes with some versions, which adds a hefty 2 Mb) so you're not saving much by deleting it.

Comment: Great, is good to know! I decided to delete it because I don't like unnecessary apps rather than space saving but atleast it hasn't broken anything.